# Употребление склоняемых названий в контексте

Tags: прописная-строчная

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь со следующим предложением?..

**Эти игры получили название Олимпиады континентального масштаба.**

Знаю, что когда название склоняется *(не название "Олимпиада", а название олимпиады),* то кавычки здесь не нужны. Но вопрос: нужно ли писать слова **"Олимпиада континентального масштаба"** с прописной буквы, если вообще это название везде пишется с прописной?..

Comment: Эта страна получила название Соединённых штатов Америки?

Comment: Ну да, правильно... Гениальный ответ... Заучилась...

Comment: Ну я-то за прописную изначально и была...

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет (при склонении названия) перестроить фразу, исключив родовое слово: «Эти игры стали Олимпиадой континентального масштаба».

Comment: Это хороший вариант, но перестраивать ничего нельзя, и хочется использовать правильную орфографию именно в моем варианте.

Comment: Но все равно спасибо...